# nginx config files redirecting to subfolder

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, subdomain

I'm currently trying to deploy a website in two directories. Despite the lot of documentations on it, I was not able to obtain the behavior that I wish. This is the architecture of the websites :

- The main website page is stored in /opt/www/mainsite/index.html
- The second webiste (working with CodeIgniter) is stored in /opt/www/apps/myapp/index.php

I wish configure nginx to obtain this behavior :

- All requests in http must be redirect to https
- www.mydomain.com must point to /opt/www/mainsite/index.html
- www.mydomain.com/myapp must point to /opt/www/apps/myapp/index.php

currently, my config file contains :

```
# redirect http to https
server {
    listen 80;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

# main webiste
server {
    listen 443;

    # ssl elements...  
    root   /opt/www/mainsite;
    index index.html;
    server_name             www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

On this [page](http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter) I found all the informations to set the config file for CodeIgniter. But I don't know how to create the rules to point mydomain.com/myapp on the CodeIgniter folder and how to configure  CodeIgniter in order to set the right configuration.

Is anybody can help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule to setup CodeIgniter.
- Using 2 server blocks is better than using if block for redirect. See [IF is Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).
- Don't use $host because that variable value is obtained from the request's HOST header, and can be easily faked. Always set a server_name directive and use that name instead.
- Using "return 301" directive is better than a rewrite. Saving cpu time (regex is slow) and easy to follow. Note that a 302 redirect (rewrite...redirect) has side effect because 302 will turn all POST requests to GET requests, which is not good in your case.
- You don't need try_files in the main site because the main site just serves static files. But you can use 'expires' directive to allow browser to cache the static files.

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name www.mydomain.com;
>     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
>  }
>
>  server {
>     listen 443;
>     server_name www.mydomain.com;
>     # ssl elements...  
>
>     location / {
>         root   /opt/www/mainsite;
>         index index.html;
>         expires max;
>     }
>
>     location /myapp {
>         root /opt/www/apps/myapp;
>         # fastcgi module goes here...
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful response and all the details! My app is now working, but the folder "assets" is not available and return an error 404 (https://www.mydomain.com/myapp/assets must point to /opt/www/apps/myapp/assets but it does not works). Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Add another location block for the assets such that you can allow browser to cache those static files as well.. Nginx wiki has a webpage for this. http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    …
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? redirect;
    }
    root /opt/www/mainsite/;
    location /myapp {
        root /opt/www/apps/myapp/;
    }
}
```

You'd put whatever configuration that is necessary for your `myapp` within the `location` for `myapp`.

BTW, it is generally a bad idea to host multiple independent apps within a single `Host`, because of XSS concerns.